# Issues trying to install ubuntu 18.04 via usb bootable device

Tags: linux, bootable-media

i am trying to set up a ubuntu linux setup via bootable device. Whenever i try to boot, the ubuntu wallpaper/picture(?) Shows up and then it goes all blank with an underscore "_" blinking at the top. It happens with both dd mode and iso mode installed via rufus. Is my version of ubuntu iso corrupt or am i doing something wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Insufficient information.

Comment: You could try CTRL+ALT+F1 to possibly get an shell prompt;  if it appears: enter `dmesg | less` and then hit `>` to see the last lines (and h for help). Then tell us what you see.

Comment: You could also boot into "try mode" - which could well work as it loads more [display] drivers (I believe).